# Yet another wifi issue in Ubuntu with Qualcomm QCA6174..."WI-FI networks device not ready"

Tags: wireless, atheros

I have probably read every single piece of advice out there for fixing this issue to no avail.  To make a long story short:

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot. Wireless does not work.

I have tried many fixes that are offered for this and none work.

I have tried manual switch off and on (although it does nothing when I hit fn + F3), connecting to wired (through an adapter), multiple times of reinstalling and updating.  I even read something that talked about releasing the wifi in windows first but that didn't work either.

I have tried this step from another user:

> *"I managed to get the wireless working. The trick is as follows: (1) Create a folder called /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174 (2) Make sure
>   there are two subfolders, /hw2.1 and /hw3.0 (3) Copy the files found
>   here into the appropriate subfolders:
>   https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware (4) Note that the files named
>   "firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1" in the hw3.0 subfolder
>   and "firmware-5.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1" in the hw2.1
>   subfolder should be renamed "firmware-4.bin" and "firmware-5.bin"
>   respectively. (This was what was causing issues for me in the first
>   place)."*

I am getting 
*-network DISABLED 
when I type
sudo lshw -C network

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and have exhausted all resources that I know.  Any help would be appreciated.

edit*
Here is my report from 
rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth  
Soft blocked: yes   
Hard blocked: no 
1:acer-wireless: Wireless LAN   
Soft blocked: no    
Hard blocked: no 
2:acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth     
Soft blocked: yes   
Hard blocked: no 
3:phy0: Wireless LAN    
Soft blocked: no    
Hard blocked: no
```

I had turned off bluetooth bc someone mention that might be a solution, but it did nothing.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `rfkill list all`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Try `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb` and then
`sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb`  Reboot

Answer (score 0):

*Update

I was able to get it to work by doing what Jeremy31 said:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.158_all.deb
```